# For loop - 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, sum

I'm a beginner and I've been stuck for hours. I have problems with a simple for loop. I want an alert box that gives me the sum of the bars controlled by the player (it's part of the code for a simple boardgame)

This is my code:

```
    var districts = [{bars:0}, {bars:2}, {bars:2}, {bars:3}, {bars:0}, {bars:3}]; //these are all the districts in the game + the amount of bars on them
    var PlayerControlledDistricts = [districts[0], districts[2], districts[3]]; //these are the 3 districts the player controlls
    var AmountOfBars = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <=PlayerControlledDistricts.length; i++){
             AmountOfBars += parseInt(PlayerControlledDistricts[i].bars, 10);
             }
    alert(AmountOfBars);
```

What is wrong with this code? If I put an alertbox inside the for loop i get: 0, 2, 5 - so I suppose everything is fine inside the loop - but once I put the alertbox outside the loop nothing happens at all...

Comment: You don't need to `parseInt` since you already have numbers.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <PlayerControlledDistricts.length; i++)` - since an array starts at 0 and its length starts at 1, you need to count only to `PlayerControlledDistricts.length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you loop one too many elements, use `<` instead of `<=`

```
var districts = [{bars:0}, {bars:2}, {bars:2}, {bars:3}, {bars:0}, {bars:3}]; //these are all the districts in the game + the amount of bars on them
var PlayerControlledDistricts = [districts[0], districts[2], districts[3]]; //these are the 3 districts the player controlls
var AmountOfBars = 0;
for (i = 0; i < PlayerControlledDistricts.length; i++){
         AmountOfBars += parseInt(PlayerControlledDistricts[i].bars, 10);
}
alert(AmountOfBars);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7z0qhkqr/)

---

As pointed out by @Jamiec, you don't actually need to parse the number, as you already have it as a number, so just do:

```
AmountOfBars += PlayerControlledDistricts[i].bars;
```

Comment: get rid of the `parseInt` OP doesnt need it

Comment: That is true, I will add as a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<` instead of `<=`!

```js
var districts = [{bars:0}, {bars:2}, {bars:2}, {bars:3}, {bars:0}, {bars:3}]; //these are all the districts in the game + the amount of bars on them
var PlayerControlledDistricts = [districts[0], districts[2], districts[3]]; //these are the 3 districts the player controlls
var AmountOfBars = 0;
for (i = 0; i < PlayerControlledDistricts.length; i++) {
  debugger;
  AmountOfBars += parseInt(PlayerControlledDistricts[i].bars, 10);
}
alert(AmountOfBars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < PlayerControlledDistricts.length; i++)`
```

This is because an array starts at 0 and its length starts at 1, you need to count only up to `PlayerControlledDistricts.length`, as `PlayerControlledDistricts.length` itself is 1 higher than the indexes of the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your iteration -- you are iterating to `i <=PlayerControlledDistricts.length` which is one more than you need so end up asking for `PlayerControlledDistricts[3]` on the last loop which is undefined. You also don't need `parseInt` as you already have a numeric value. Here is a working example using console.log:

```
var districts = [{bars:0}, {bars:2}, {bars:2}, {bars:3}, {bars:0}, {bars:3}]; //these are all the districts in the game + the amount of bars on them
var PlayerControlledDistricts = [districts[0], districts[2], districts[3]]; //these are the 3 districts the player controlls
var AmountOfBars = 0;
for (i = 0; i < PlayerControlledDistricts.length; i++) {
         AmountOfBars += PlayerControlledDistricts[i].bars;
}
console.log(AmountOfBars);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eofbenw2/

Answer (score 0):

The index of the array was the Issue, because remember that the elements of the array should be 0.....to n-1 because the length attribute has n elements.
so if you have an array with 10 elements, so the length will be 10, and the element store between 0 to 9.

After that it's a good practice inicializate the loop for with var for(var i=0;condition;increment);

Additional you don't need the conversion.

I could recommend you use the [Console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) Method to validate the information and objects, that console print in the console of your web browser (you could watch with F12 in the console tab).

```
var districts = [{bars:0}, {bars:2}, {bars:2}, {bars:3}, {bars:0}, {bars:3}]; //these are all the districts in the game + the amount of bars on them
var PlayerControlledDistricts = [districts[0], districts[2], districts[3]]; //these are the 3 districts the player controlls
var AmountOfBars = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <PlayerControlledDistricts.length; i++)
        AmountOfBars += PlayerControlledDistricts[i].bars;

alert(AmountOfBars);
```

Regards